# #1071 - Specified key was too long issue

Tags: mysql

This question can be somehow continuation of [MySQL unique 1500 varchar field error (#1071 - Specified key was too long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009510/mysql-unique-1500-varchar-field-error-1071-specified-key-was-too-long), but briefly:

I applied changes to mysql configuaration and increased key/unique length to 3072 bytes

```
ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC, innodb_file_format = Barracuda, innodb_large_prefix = true
```

If I do:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `link` varchar(1500) NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastvisited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;

ALTER TABLE  `pages` ADD UNIQUE (
`link`
)
```

I got error: "#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 3072 bytes" what is right, as link is varchar(1500) and is 4500 bytes.

Now, with same configuration, I decided to apply next table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pages` (
  `link` varchar(1500) CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin NOT NULL,
  `domain` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastvisited` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `link` (`link`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC;
```

And I get error:

```
#1709 - Index column size too large. The maximum column size is 767 bytes.
```

All changes that were made is CHARACTER SET, but this decreased column size to 767 bytes. No changes to configuration. 
Why?

Comment: Just an idea, but instead of trying to ensure that a 1500 char URL is unique, why not also store a [hash](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha1) of the `URL` and then check just the hashes. Sure, some tiny chance of collision ...

Comment: Great idea! What about benefits? So when insert I just checking for hash, if 0 rows- insert, if some exists, select all and do next url checking.

Comment: Well, the main benefit is speed - the hash will be a few bytes, which can be safely indexed. The downside is that it needs to be computed before an insert.

Comment: So my insert will be like, insert if not exists (select * where hash = '' and link = ''),
Is there a way to optimize it?

Comment: I suppose construction 'insert on dublicate key' will not work here, as I can not make hash a key.

Comment: Hash would make a good key - the duplicate key should work fine. Unfortunately sqlfiddle seems dead at the moment.

Comment: What if 2 url's create same hash? The probality is small, but it is!