# Created Directory's name encoding confusing

Tags: java

I would like to create a directory name which contains some non-ASCII characters. For example:

```
File exampleDir = new File(fullPath + File.separator + "ĞÜŞİÖÇ-ğüşiöç");
exampledir.mkdir();
```

But this created directory name like `c:\test\Ä�ÃœÅ�Ä°Ã–Ã‡-ÄŸÃ¼ÅŸiÃ¶Ã§` instead of `c:\test\ĞÜŞİÖÇ-ğüşiöç.jpg`.

I tried to start the JVM with `-Dfile.encoding=UTF8` but that didn't change anything.

Comment: have a look on  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978747/problems-in-jcifs-with-certain-non-ascii-characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **class file** are not compiled with correct encoding.
I can reproduce the problem:

1. Create java source file and save it using UTF-8 encoding.
2. Compiled it with other encoding (For example: `javac -encoding ISO-8859-1 Test.java`)